# Looking for a way to prevent IE reloading tabs

Tags: 8.1, internet-explorer

Whenever I want to check an already opened page (when switching between tabs or applications), Internet Explorer reloads the page. As a consequence, I can't keep opened pages without internet access. Is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: You can reproduce this switching from one tab to another a fraction of a minute? I'm experienced many apps opened for a long time are doing a refresh like they had been open again.

Comment: Indeed, just switching to anything then immediatly coming back makes ie reload the page.

Comment: It does this because memory (RAM) gets low from using multiple apps, so web pages must be unloaded - I assume pinning the website to the Start Screen has no affect? how about taking a screenshot?

Comment: I tried without any opened applications, it keeps doing the same. Regarding screenshots, what would you like to see ?

Comment: @fxm I think Neil was suggesting that you'd take a screenshot of the page before connection is lost, so that you can still have a look at the page once offline. It might be a handy hack for some cases but of course it comes with quite a severe limitation: no scrolling of content.

Comment: @Crono I see, I thought it was about the post:) However, as you point out, this is a poor work-around. Are there other web browser which don't suffer from this "feature" ?

Comment: UC Browser doesn't do this. I have to say, it is super annoying especially on slow internet connections. I used an iPad the other day that behaved the same way

Comment: @fxm, what phone are you using?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder a Nokia lumia 520

Comment: @fxm then it probably has to do with the amount of ram in your phone. You can probably have multiple small tabs open at the same time but huge tabs might be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabs that you've used stay in memory as long as Internet Explorer stays in memory (i.e. it shows in the list when pressing, and holding the back button). If the Internet Explorer falls off the list of running applications, the open tabs are preserved, but are refreshed the next time you use them - this is the same behaviour as the desktop version (and, for that matter, for competitor browsers, such as Firefox on the desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Why it reloads the page. For once see it from Mobile's point of view.

**Why purge previous page :** If it is not having to reload the page then it has to hold the page data somewhere into memory and keep a pointer/object busy into stack. Meaningfully more memory will be used and phone will be prone to hanged. To avoid such a tragedy that your window's phone getting hanged/freeze Microsoft has not allowed this. This is an advantage.

**Alternative solution** : You can use **Mozilla's firefox web browser** in your windows phone. This browser keep the hold of previous loaded page. It will suite your need but still might get hanged. Hope you understand the compromise on memory.

*Windows phone are famous for their UX(user experience) UI(design  etc) fast and fluid experience.*

Comment: where can I download Firefox?